# Print contents of a file and count the number of lines in the file - Python

Tags: python

Taking an intro to programming course using python.

Our task this week is to create a text file called 'randomnum.txt' and print to it using a python script. I was able to successfully create the file but am met with the second part of the assignment to print the contents of the file AND count the number of numbers (lines) in the .txt.

I have been able to print the contents or count the number of lines but never both. I'm pretty bad at Python and would like some help.

```
with open ('randomnum.txt','r') as random_numbers:
    num_nums = 0  
    contents = random_numbers.read()
    for lines in random_numbers:
        num_nums += 1
    print('List of random numbers in randomnum.txt')
    print(contents)
    print('Random number count: ', num_nums)
```

This way it gives me a random number count of 0.

any help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question because you're observing the behaviour that you can only read a file object once. Once you call `random_numbers.read()`, you can not repeat that action.

What I recommend is instead of doing `.read()`, use `.readlines()`. It reads each line one-by-one instead of reading the whole file at once. While iterating through each line, add one to your counter and print the current line:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as myfile:
    total = 0
    for line in myfile.readlines():
        print(line, end="")
        total += 1
    print("Total: " + str(total))
```

Note the second parameter I pass through to print (`end=""`). This is because by default `print` adds a newline, but since the file will already have newlines at the end of the line, you would be printing two new lines. `end=""` stops the behaviour of `print` printing a trailing newline.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `readlines` then `map` for stripping, using the method descriptor for it, then just use `len` for getting length:

```
with open ('randomnum.txt','r') as random_numbers:
    l=random_numbers.readlines()
    print('List of random numbers in randomnum.txt')
    print(''.join(map(str.rstrip,l)))
    print('Random number count: ', len(l))
```

Output of code with `randomnum.txt` as:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Output:

```
List of random numbers in randomnum.txt
123456
Random number count:  6
```

Answer (score -1):

Calling `.read()` and iterating with `for ... in ...` both consume the contents of the file. You can't do both unless you call `.seek(0)` in between. Alternatively, instead of calling `.read()`, you could capture the lines in your `for` loop (maybe switch to `.readlines()`) and then not worry about it.